# Can't install apache2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, apache2

I want to install apache
when I type :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libapache2-mpm-itk:i386 libapache2-mpm-itk

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

I tried many solutions and they didn't work for me
what should I do ?

Output of `sudo apt update` as requested:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                            
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                               
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-brightness/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: I've added the output to your question. For future clarifications, please [edit] your question to add information :)

Comment: On my 18.04 system `apache2` is in the `bionic/main` repository: `...us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main`. Do you have that enabled? You might as well remove that non-working `ubuntu-wine` ppa while you are at it.

Comment: thank you @Organic_Marble, that was the right solution for me !
apache is working now but when i do : 
'sudo apt autoremove' 
i get this error :
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
 installed javascript-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to solve my own problem, I am posting this for informative use incase anyone reads it later down the line:
first, as @Marble told me to do, i removed the `ubuntu-wine` from Software&updates -> Other Software.
=> apache2 was installed
then, to solve the problem relateed to javascript-common
i entered these commandes :

```
apt-get remove javascript-common

apt-get --purge remove javascript-common

apt-get purge javascript-common
```

now problem solved :)